# basic - multiple categories from each item at foreach loop in PHP/mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I've got table of categories. One item may have more than one category in table3. Three tables as below:

table1:

```
ID  Item_id
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

table2:

```
   ID Item_id Category
   1   1  catId_1
   2   2  catId_1
   3   2  catId_2
   4   3  catId_2
   5   3  catId_3
   6   3  catId_4
   7   4  catId_2
   8   5  catId_1
   etc.
```

third table has only information of the name of category:

table3:

```
Category_id  category_name
catId_1     cats
catId_2     dogs
catId_3     IT_managers
catId_4     Trump_lovers
```

I made a query to get PDO object of all items and be able to get categories from each one in php.

First query:

```
public function getCategories(){
$this->db->query('SELECT table1.*, table2.*, table3.*
       FROM table1
       INNER JOIN table2
       ON table1.item_id = table2.item_id
       INNER JOIN table3
       ON table2.category=table3.category_id');

$results = $this->db->resultset();
return $results;}

$items = $offer_class -> getCategories();
```

How can I take all category name of each item in foreach loop?

I've tried this foreach loop, but it gives me only first category for each item:

```
<?php foreach($items as $item){
echo $item->category_name; 
}
?>
```

Comment: There's no point selecting anything from table2. Just sayin'

Comment: @Strawberry-  you are right

Answer (score 0):

You could split it up in 2 queries. - One query to find the needed in Table1,Table2 and an other query to find the category_name which matches the items.

In your foreach loop you'll then make a new foreach loop where you list the category_name data.

Regarding to your comment, you could do it like this:

```
<?php

$items = array("test", "test2",array("CAT1","CAT2","CAT3","CAT4"));



foreach($items as $t)
{
    if(!is_array($t))
    {
        echo $t;
    } 
    else
    {

        foreach($t as $ar)
        {
            echo $ar . " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sure, that might work, but I assume that the result of current query has both categories. My question is rather - how to get them both from the $items object for each item

Comment: Updated the answer to fit your wish.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll look at it soon and write if it works

Comment: @gileneusz - You have any feedback regarding this answer is accepted?

Comment: not yet, I'll look at this today. I skipped this problem and I have looked after jscripts, but I still remember, sorry for this delay

Comment: I'm affraid that your solution will not work, because the result of PDO query is an object, not an array.